# If $E$ denotes $n$ sets of size $k$, what is the minimum possible number of subsets of sets in $E$ of size $d$, $d<k$?

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $X$ be a set of size $N$ and $E$ be a family of subsets of $X$ of size $k \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. $E\subseteq [X]^k$, with $k\geq 2$.

Fix $1\leq d <k$. Let $U$ denote the family of subsets of $X$ of size $d$ that are also subsets of some set in $E$. What is the minimum possible size of $U$?

For example, if $E=[X]^k$ then $|E|= \binom{N}{k}$ and $|U|= \binom{N}{d}$, so
$$
|U|=|E|\frac{(N-k)!}{(N-d)!}\frac{k!}{d!}.
$$
Is this optimal?

Note moreover that, since $|E|<N^k$ and, for $N$ large enough (or $|E|$ large enough), $U > N^{d-1}$, then for $E$ large enough, we have that
$$
|U| > |E|^{\frac{d-1}{k}}. 
$$
Does this inequality hold for every possible $E$?

Comment: Do you want to find the minimum possible number of subsets, or the minimum possible ratio of subsets, or some other constraint entirely? The title, "is this optimal?" and "does this inequality hold" seem to refer to 3 distinct considerations.

Comment: So $d$ and $k$ are fixed. I am interested in the minimum possible number (or a nice lower bound), hopefully as a function of $|E|$ alone, however a solution that involves $N$ too might be sufficient to achieve this and I could also accept.